# Is there a way to order the columns (sliced with iloc) in pandas as the main dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to separate columns by slicing them because I need to assign `dtypes` for each one. So I grouped them by `dtypes` and assign their respective `dtype` and now I want to join or concat and that has the same column order as the main dataframe. I add that is not possible to do it by its column name because it may change.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf8') #It has 11 columns
intg = file.iloc[:,[0,2,4,6,8,9,11]].astype("Int64")
obj = file.iloc[:,[1,3,5,7,10]].astype(str)
```

After doing this I need to join them with the same order as the main file, that is from 0 to 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join these 2 chunks you can use the `join` function, then reindex based on your original dataframes columns. Should look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf8') #It has 11 columns
intg = file.iloc[:,[0,2,4,6,8,9,11]].astype("Int64")
obj = file.iloc[:,[1,3,5,7,10]].astype(str)

out = pd.join(intg, obj).reindex(file.columns, axis="columns")
```